# When iOS terminates an app which ViewController is started when the app opens up again?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In android when an application is terminated by the os, the activity stack remains intact when the app is opened up again. Does something similar happen when an ios app is terminated and reopened, or does the app behave as if it's being opened from a cold start?

Comment: I am pretty sure that even on Android the state restoration is not automatic. You have to do some work for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops- better answers below.  We have both learned something new today

cold start.  If you want to restore state, you will need to keep a track of where you are, and what data has been loaded (maybe in NSUserDefault) and restore state manually

Comment: Not really. Preserving and restoring view controllers is supported natively. You just have to turn it on. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the concept of state restoration. There is restoration ID for every view controller in storyboard. When the App is terminated and launched again then you can navigate to the same state where the App has terminated by using the concept of restoration. You can go through the below link for to get the steps of implementation

https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html